# How to match the last word in a sentence?

Tags: java, regex

Suppose we have *one* sentence (several words without a dot after the last one).

I need to wrap the last word with some html tags (for example, `<strong>lastword</strong>`).

How can I achieve this with java regular expressions?

I've already tried this:

```
"John Doe Jr".replaceAll ("( .+$)", "<strong>$1</strong>");
```

but it results in

```
John<strong> Doe Jr</strong>
```

p.s. It's ok if we have a whitespace after `<strong>`, the main problem is that the pattern matches the biggest subsequence while I need the smallest one.

Comment: Are you not concerned that the meaning of a dot is ambiguous? As well as marking the end of sentence, it's used in abbreviations, numbers, ellipsis, dates, domain names etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"John Doe Jr".replaceAll("(\\S+)$", "<strong>$1</strong>")
```

[\S](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) is a non-whitespace character

Comment: `\\S is not a space operator` is bad wording. The official definition is: `A non-whitespace character: [^\s]` (see here: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html )

Answer (score 2):

The last word would be the non-space characters preceding the end or the string. You can define a set of characters with [] and negate that with a ^, as in [^a-z] to match everything but a-z.

```
"John Doe Jr".replaceAll("([^ ]+)$", "<strong>$1</strong>");
```

This also has the advantage that it doesn't require that there be any spaces in the string, unlike Marcelo Cantos' answer.